# Rocket Engine - Actuator in Loop Simulations

Tags: rockets, simulation, electronics, flight-control, ariane

For Actuator-In-Loop simulations, why are the rocket engine nozzles along with the thrust vector control assembly (including the actuators) kept inverted on a platform like in the attached image or as in the Youtube video for an Ariane launch vehicle simulator?
Are there any structural reasons for the same (e.g. to avoid exciting any modes) ?

[image: Actuator-In-Loop simulator, VSSC, India]

Comment: Inverted, the gimbal is bearing the weight of the nozzle, which better models the forces that will be in play in flight (where it will be bearing the full thrust force of the engine).

Comment: @RussellBorogove But that will be either way, right? Even in upright position, gimbal will be bearing the weight of the nozzle (even more accurately as that of the flight condition). I haven't seen this inverted configuration during RS-25 (SSME/SLS) testing. Is it only specific to Ariane 5's engine testing?

Comment: @OrangeDurito Not the same part of the gimbal, in a *non-firing* actuator test. The part that's loaded if you hold the rocket body and let the engine hang, only has to carry the weight of the engine, so it can be designed very differently from the business end of the gimbal bearing.